# Fast way to use dictionary in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a question about pyspark.

I have dataframe with 2 columns "country" and "web". I need to save this dataframe as dictionary to iterate through it later another dataframe column.

I am saving dictionaru like this:

```
sorted_dict = result.rdd.sortByKey()
```

But when I am trying to iterate through it I have an exception:

> "It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an " Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example SPARK-5063

I understood that I can't use two RDDs together, but unfortunately I dont know how to use SparkContext.broadcast in this way, because I have an error

> TypeError: broadcast() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'value'

Can anyone help me do get it clear? I need to make dictionary from dataframe:

```
+--------------------+-------+
|                 web|country|
+--------------------+-------+
|   alsudanalyoum.com|     SD|
|periodicoequilibr...|     SV|
|  telesurenglish.net|     UK|
|         nytimes.com|     US|
|portaldenoticias....|     AR|
+----------------------------+
```

Then take another dataframe:

```
+--------------------+-------+
|           split_url|country|
+--------------------+-------+
|   alsudanalyoum.com|   Null|
|periodicoequilibr...|   Null|
|  telesurenglish.net|   Null|
|         nytimes.com|   Null|
|portaldenoticias....|   Null|
+----------------------------+
```

... and put values of dictionary to country column.

P.S. join does not fit for me because of other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you should use `join()`, but since you cannot, you can combine the use of `df.rdd.collectAsMap()` and `pyspark.sql.functions.create_map()` and `itertools.chain` to achieve the same thing.

NB: `sortByKey()` does not return a dictionary (or a map), but instead returns a sorted `RDD`.

```
from itertools import chain
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
   ("a", 5),
   ("b", 20),
   ("c", 10),
   ("d", 1),
], ["key", "value"])

# create map from the origin df
rdd_map = df.rdd.collectAsMap()

# yes, these are not real null values, but here it doesn't matter
df_target = spark.createDataFrame([
   ("a", "NULL"),
   ("b", "NULL"),
   ("c", "NULL"),
   ("d", "NULL"),
], ["key", "value"])

df_target.show()
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  a| NULL|
|  b| NULL|
|  c| NULL|
|  d| NULL|
+---+-----+

value_map = f.create_map(
    [f.lit(x) for x in chain(*rdd_map.items())]
)

# map over the "key" column into the "value" column
df_target.withColumn(
    "value",
    value_map[f.col("key")]
).show()
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  a|    5|
|  b|   20|
|  c|   10|
|  d|    1|
+---+-----+
```